# Have equal space in awk printf

Tags: shell, awk, printf

I have a csv file with following content.

```
"TELUS","Vancouver Canada","67.151","0.325","0","63247942","64210661","768241424","858087937"
"TELUS","Vancouver Canada","7.151","0.325","0","63247942","64210661","768241424","858087937"
```

With the help of awk, I have successfully parsing them to readable format.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/"/, ""); printf "| %-11s | %-17s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-5.16s |\n", $1, $2, $7/125000, "MB/s", $6/125000, "MB/s", ($8+$9)/(1000*1000*1000), "GB", $3, "ms" }'
```

Return this

```
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 67.2 ms    |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 7.2 ms    |
```

But as you can see the space is not equal on latency field. I want it to be like this.

```
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 67.2 ms   |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 7.2 ms    |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 947.2 ms  |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 7241.2 ms |
```

I'm putting two extra field at above, the point is I want to keep the column spacing intact no matter how large the latency is. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try { **`%9.3f %-3.16s`** }:

```
echo "${a}" | mawk  '{ gsub(/[\42]/,"")

    printf "| %-11s | %-17s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-6s  "\
           "| %.1f %-6s | %9.3f %-3.16s |\n",\
                $1        ,     $2,
                $7 * 8E-6 , "MB/s",\
                $6 * 8E-6 , "MB/s", \
            ($8+$9)*(1E-9), "GB"  , $3, "ms" }' FS=','

| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s    | 1.6 GB     |    67.151 ms  |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s    | 1.6 GB     |     7.151 ms  |
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hard-coding field widths, just use `awk` to calculate the values and `column` to calculate the widths:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/"/, ""); printf ",%s,%s,%.1f MB/s,%.1f MB/s,%.1f GB,%.1f ms, \n", $1, $2, $7/125000, $6/125000, ($8+$9)/(1000*1000*1000), $3}' file |
    column -t -s',' -o' | ' | sed 's/^ //; s/ $//'
| TELUS | Vancouver Canada | 513.7 MB/s | 506.0 MB/s | 1.6 GB | 67.2 ms |
| TELUS | Vancouver Canada | 513.7 MB/s | 506.0 MB/s | 1.6 GB | 7.2 ms  |
```

but if you want to do the formatting in awk then again separate the field widths (e.g. `%-17s`) from the field contents (e.g. rounding to `%.1f`):

```
$ awk -F, -v CONVFMT='%.1f' '{gsub(/"/, ""); printf "| %-11s | %-17s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s |\n", $1, $2, $7/125000 " MB/s", $6/125000 " MB/s", ($8+$9)/(1000*1000*1000) " GB", $3 " ms" }' file
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s | 506.0 MB/s | 1.6 GB     | 67.151 ms  |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s | 506.0 MB/s | 1.6 GB     | 7.151 ms   |
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
cat fmt.awk
{
   gsub(/"/, "")
   printf ("| %-11s | %-17s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-6s | %.1f %-6s | %-10s |\n",
      $1, $2, $7/125000, "MB/s", $6/125000, "MB/s", ($8+$9)/(1000*1000*1000),
      "GB", sprintf("%.1f ms", $3))
}

awk -F, -f fmt.awk file.csv

| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 67.2 ms    |
| TELUS       | Vancouver Canada  | 513.7 MB/s   | 506.0 MB/s   | 1.6 GB     | 7.2 ms     |
```

Used `sprintf("%.1f ms", $3)` to get single digit decimal point in `$3` followed by  `ms`. This is formatted in main `printf` with `%-10s` formatting to get left aligned output with `width=10`.

To get last column right aligned use `%10s` formatting.